# Enable and Disable td in table

Tags: javascript, html

```
<td><select class="dropDownLists" name=reportFlag id="reportFlag" tabindex="10" style="WIDTH: 160px" onchange='onFocusReportingOptions();'> 
        <option value="Select">Select</option>
        <option value="Y">Yes</option>
        <option value="N">No</option>
        </select>    
</td>
```

**After I select the option Yes or No, below TD's should be shown or not to the user.**

```
<td id="first_td"><select class="dropDownLists" name=reportingOption id="reportFlag" tabindex="10" style="WIDTH: 160px" onchange='callonChange();'> 
        <option value="Select">Select</option>
        <option value="MyTell">Report via tool</option>
        <option value="Manual">Report via manually</option>
        </select>
</td>
<td id="second_td"><select class="dropDownLists" name=acctFlag id="acctFlag" tabindex="10" style="WIDTH: 160px" onchange='callonChange();'> 
        <option value="Select">Select</option>
        <option value="Y">Yes</option>
        <option value="N">No</option>
        </select>
</td>
```

My questions what are the ways to control the display of the td?
one way I can do is with the DIV tags but if we use Div tag i learnt that we need to use table inside the td,  in that case then the alignment will be a problem

can any one suggest any other way to get this implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the TDs an ID. Then use Javascript to hide the element with the relevant ID (via the CSS display attribute).

```
<td id="first_td">content</td>
<td id="second_id"><content</td>

var elem = document.getElementById("first_td");
elem.style.display = "none";
```

The logic for which TD is hidden or shown can be encapsulated in an event handler for the select drop-down.

Comment: I implemented as per your response, when i select No in the first option, the following the td id="first_td" is disappearing but in that place id="second_td" is displaying, the other td should not move once I make the first_td as display none..

Comment: You are hiding one of the TD elements, so the other one will move. If that is making the table look weird, then give each TD in a column a class name and hide the entire class - that will hide a whole column, which should stop the table from looking strange.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the style visibility instead of display.

Check this code, if this the one suit your needs.

**CSS**

```
    .hiddenTD{
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .visibleTD{
        visibility: visible;
    }
```

**JS**

```
function onFocusReportingOptions(val){
    var firstTD = document.getElementById('first_td');
    var secondTD = document.getElementById('second_td');

    if(val == 'Y') {
        firstTD.className = "visibleTD";
        secondTD.className = "visibleTD";
    } else {
        firstTD.className = "hiddenTD";
        secondTD.className = "hiddenTD";        
    }

}
```

Change something on your HTML

```
<td>
        <select class="dropDownLists" name=reportFlag id="reportFlag" tabindex="10" style="WIDTH: 160px" onchange='onFocusReportingOptions(this.value);'> 
        <option value="Select">Select</option>
        <option value="Y">Yes</option>
        <option value="N">No</option>
        </select>    
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you would like imitate "disable"(not hide)

```
$('td.YOUR CLASS').css('opacity', '0.5').click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using tables for layout?! Use divs like such:

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/HpDjL/)

Then you can easily style it to your needs. (Positioning, etc.)