# document.getElementById("").disabled not working in Chrome & IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

document.getElementById().disabled for cell is working in IE8. But not working in Chrome & IE11. I have pasted similar code tried in w3schools try it editor. My requirement is similar to disable the td element and not the button. I tried display.none. But that completely removes the cell element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table width="400" border="0">
<tr>
<td width="64" id="Submit">
<button id="myBtn">My Button</button>
</td>
</tr>
<p>Click the button below to disable the button above.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("Submit").disabled=true;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
<td width="64" id="Submit">
  <a href="#" title="<s:text name="Submit"/>" onClick="if(!this.disabled){fn_Submit();" >
    <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing="0" class="menublue" style="cursor:hand">
      <tr>
        <td width="10"><img src="../image/button_left_part.gif" width="10" height="23" border="0" ></td>
        <td  nowrap="true" align="left" background="../image/button_middle_part.gif"><span class="buttonText"><s:text name="Submit"/></span></td>
        <td width="10"><img src="../image/button_right_part.gif" width="10" height="23" border="0" ></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </a>
</td>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737512/document-getelementbyidbtnid-disabled-is-not-working-in-firefox-and-chrome

This is the correct usage

Comment: In my code I do not have a button, I have a link, images and text inside a td cell which makes it look like a button. So I need to disable the entire cell to disable that link. If possible to disable the link also fine.

Comment: `disabled` is only recognized on forms and form fields. A `<td>` isn't designed to apply a disable state to fields contained within it.

Comment: Setting the disabled attribute on a table call is invalid HTML

Comment: You have to imitate the disabled behaviour somehow.. like preventing click on it Or putting another div on the top it..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815654/enable-and-disable-td-in-table

Comment: I'm not sure this is a dupe

Comment: @Jocket The advice in many of the answers of that Q&A seem dated and rather backwards. Though a few still do, attributes aren't intended to keep state as it's modified. That role belongs to the element's properties. https://jsfiddle.net/h004nt74/

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table width="400" border="0">
<tr>
<td width="64" id="Submit">
<button id="myBtn">My Button</button>
</td>
</tr>
<p>Click the button below to disable the button above.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction(this)">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction(button) {
    button.disabled = true;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

See if this works, hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

Keep removing things to simplify it until you spot the error.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("Submit").disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">myFunction</button>
  <button id="Submit">Submit</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: We are using a customized kind of button through out the app. Update the question with exact cell code.

Comment: Did you seriously downvote my answer because I didn't use your custom code? Do you think this is a code writing service?

Comment: Will -- I did not downvote your answer.. I could've done it accidentally since I was looking at the answers from my phone..

Comment: I must be feeling a little sensitive. 